# Bootstrap Carousel Change Event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc, carousel

I have a web app which has been wrote in ASP.Net Core. I have created a bootstrap carousel and dynamically add photos to it from a SQL database. In my SQL table I store the photo path and a notes column. I need to write a routine so that when the carousel changes photos either next or previous I need to get the notes from list I pass to the view. I think I need to use JQuery to trap for the change event of the carousel but not sure how I do this and how I get the notes.

ViewModel:

```html
    public class PhotosViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<JobPhotos> PhotosList { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public List<IFormFile> Photos { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my code in my view:

```html
<div id="divCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                @for (var photoCount = 0; photoCount < Model.PhotosList.Count(); photoCount++)
                {
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    if (photoCount == 0)
                    {
                        <li data-target="#divCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li data-target="#divCarousel" data-slide-to=@photoCount></li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
            <!-- The slideshow -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                @{
                    Int16 i = 0;
                }
                @foreach (var photo in Model.PhotosList)
                {

                    var photoPath = "~/Photos/" + photo.PhotoPath;

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="photoSize" src="@photoPath" alt="No Photo" asp-append-version="true">
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="photoSize" src="@photoPath" alt="No Photo" asp-append-version="true">
                        </div>
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#divCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#divCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start mt-3">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Photos" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input multiple asp-for="Photos" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                    <label class="custom-file-label">Choose Photo...</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start mt-1">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="DateCreated" class="col-sm-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Created Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input type="date" asp-for="DateCreated" class="form-control" placeholder="Created Date" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start mt-1">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="CreatedBy" class="col-sm-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Created By</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input asp-for="CreatedBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Created By" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <label asp-for="Notes" class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-form-label">Activity Notes</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-start">
            <div class="col-12">
                <textarea asp-for="Notes" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="15"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-2"><span class="fas fa-file-upload"></span> Create</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger float-right mt-2" asp-controller="Photos" asp-action="deletePhoto" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 20px;" )><span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span><span> Delete</span></a>
    </div>
```

Any help please,

Comment: Any help please, not sure how to take this one,

Comment: Hi @user1633508, I am a bit confused with your requirement. You have a Carousel to display the photos and some inputs below the Carousel. What does these inputs used to do? Do you want to upload new image to database and add to the Carousel?

Comment: Hi, no basically my model has a photo path, created by, created date and notes. When the view is loaded I pass a viewmodel which has a list of all the photos. Basically when the user moves to another photo I want to show the created by, created date and notes relating to the newly selected photo.

Comment: Hi @user1633508, so just for confirmation, what you want is to display the corresponding data to inputs when carousel changes photos, right?

Comment: Hi, yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot set default chosen file in browser. It would be a serious security flaw if you were able to do this via JavaScript, as you'd be able to specify any file on a user's computer, which is why you're not allowed to set the value of a file input element.

For display the corresponding data to inputs when carousel changes photos, you could follow:

View( Index.cshtml):

Note: remove `type="date"` in this line:`<input asp-for="DateCreated" class="form-control" placeholder="Created Date" readonly="readonly" />`

```
@model PhotosViewModel 
<div id="divCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        @for (var photoCount = 0; photoCount < Model.PhotosList.Count(); photoCount++)
        {
            <!-- Indicators -->
            if (photoCount == 0)
            {
                <li data-target="#divCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li data-target="#divCarousel" data-slide-to=@photoCount></li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @{
            Int16 i = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var photo in Model.PhotosList)
        {    
            var photoPath = "~/Photos/" + photo.PhotoPath;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="photoSize" src="@photoPath" alt="No Photo" asp-append-version="true" style="width:400px;height:600px;">
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="photoSize" src="@photoPath" alt="No Photo" asp-append-version="true" style="width:400px;height:600px;">
                </div>
            }
            i++;
        }
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#divCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#divCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-start mt-3">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label asp-for="Photos" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input multiple asp-for="Photos" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
            <label class="custom-file-label">Choose Photo...</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-start mt-1">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label asp-for="DateCreated" class="col-sm-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Created Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        @*remove type="date"*@
        <input asp-for="DateCreated" class="form-control" placeholder="Created Date" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-start mt-1">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label asp-for="CreatedBy" class="col-sm-2 col-md-12 col-form-label">Created By</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input asp-for="CreatedBy" class="form-control" placeholder="Created By" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label asp-for="Notes" class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-form-label">Activity Notes</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-12">
        <textarea asp-for="Notes" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="15"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-2"><span class="fas fa-file-upload"></span> Create</button>
<a class="btn btn-danger float-right mt-2" asp-controller="Photos" asp-action="deletePhoto" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 20px;" )><span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span><span> Delete</span></a>
```

JS in view:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    $('#divCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var url = $('.carousel-item.active img').attr('src');
        var photo = url.split('?');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/GetValue?path=" + photo[0],                
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                $("input#DateCreated").val(data.dateCreated);
                $("input#CreatedBy").val(data.createdBy);
                $("textarea#Notes").val(data.notes);
                }
            });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //get value from database and return it....
    return View(model);
}
public JsonResult GetValue(string path)
{
    //find the data by path from database
    //for easy testing, I hard coded the data....
    var data = new PhotosViewModel() { CreatedBy = "asd", DateCreated = new DateTime(2020,8,12),Notes="adasdasdasd" };
    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the above answer. I will be trying it in the next couple of days because I moved on to something else. I will definitely tick as answered when I get it working. Thanks again...

Comment: Hi @user1633508, ok, fine. Waiting for your response.

Comment: For some reason when I return the Json data to the ajax call and try and show the any of the fields in an alert it says undefined and my on screen input controls do not change. It is calling my method in my controller and getting the data but doesn't seem to be returning the correct data. The code is alert(data.Notes);.

Comment: Even if this did work I still have the problem of updating any changes to the notes. Even though the photo changes and the data should change, my model is still set to the first row.

Comment: Ideally when the photo changes I want to trap for that event and call a method with the currently activated model. Pass this to a method which re-populates the viewmodel and returns it to the view. I suppose I could add a another property to the viewmodel called active and before I return the view model with the list of photos tick the one I want active and do some sort of coding in the view when I populate the carousel making the correct photo active.

Comment: It should be `data.notes`.

Comment: I tried that and still get undefined message. Can you help with how I update the data if I change the notes please?

Comment: Please share your backend code if it is different from mine.

Comment: Also, did you add `console.log(data)` to check what is your response data?

Comment: I think this would partially work if I could get it going but it would not help with the updating. I have a view model as show above where I pass to the view a list of photos and a single photo. The single photo I bind to the controls using asp-for. What I am trying to do is when the next and previous buttons are pressed it updates the single photo with the newly selected one and hopefully re-binding to the notes etc show the newly selected photo details. Then when the user selects the update it would pass the view model back with the modified notes allowing me to update the database. Thanks.

Comment: I added debugger in the javascript success to see what data was and it's an object with all the data in. data looks like this Object(id: 9, customerid: 3333, photopath: "sdfsadfsads" etc. How do I access each of these elements of the object? Thanks.

Comment: Just use something like: `success: function (data) { alert(data.id)}`.

Comment: That returns undefined. unfortunately.

Comment: Please share more code to reproduce your issue. How do you return data in backend?

Comment: I have it working now thank you but the inputs are not being updated. I think this is because they are bound to the passed model. If you look at the View above you will see they are set using asp-for.

Comment: I have one slight problem with the code you kindly wrote in that I am always one photo behind. It seems the photo path is the current one when I click the next button. I need the event to fire after the new photo is shown. Any ideas please.